# I would like to connect 10 different monitors or TVs with different content - to one computer. Is this possible?

Tags: tv

I would like to connect 10 different monitors that are running 10 different power point presentations -  to one computer.

Is this possible??

Comment: Yes. Search for "multi monitor graphics card".

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible to connect that many monitors. You just need to be sure that your computer has the video output ability to support all of them (ie. video cards vs. on-board graphics).

You can have multiple instances of PowerPoint open after the 2010 version I believe, so you shouldn't have issues there.